# Helmet Content Security Policy Global Path not working

Tags: javascript, express, content-security-policy, websecurity, helmet.js

I am using Helmet to set up the content security policies of my web app in the backend using Express. The policies look like the following:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const helmet = require('helmet');

app.use(helmet());
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
      scriptSrc: ["'self'", "https://ajax.googleapis.com"],
      imgSrc: ["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com"],
      objectSrc: ["'none'"],
      styleSrc: ["'self'", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap", "https://www.w3schools.com"],
      upgradeInsecureRequests: [],
    },
  })
);
```

When my app tries to access a link such as `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css`. It says that it violates the styleSrc policy. But I have specified as one of the policies that `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap` is allowed, I thought with that `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css` would be accepted as well, since it is a child src. But apparently it gets blocked. How do I allow the child src to pass then? I have tried `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap*` but it is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of Helmet here.

Try adding a trailing slash, like this:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/
```

This is because `/bootstrap` doesn't let you do things like `/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css`, but `/bootstrap/` does. This is a Content Security Policy thing, not a Helmet thing.

For the nitty-gritty details, see step 11 of [the "Matching Source Expressions" section in the CSP spec](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/2/#match-source-expression):

> If the source expression contains a non-empty `path-part`, and the URL is *not* the result of a redirect, then:
>
> 1. Let *exact-match* be `true` if the final character of `path-part` is not the U+002F SOLIDUS character (`/`), and `false` otherwise.
> 2. Let *source-expression-path-list* be the result of splitting `path-part` on the U+002F SOLIDUS character (`/`).
> 3. If *source-expression-path-list*’s length is greater than *url-path-list*’s length, return does not match.
> 4. For each *entry* in *source-expression-path-list*:
>
>    1. Percent decode *entry*.
>    2. Percent decode the first item in *url-path-list*.
>    3. If *entry* is not an ASCII case-insensitive match for the first item in *url-path-list*, return *does not match*.
>    4. Pop the first item in *url-path-list* off the list.
> 5. If *exact-match* is `true`, and *url-path-list* is not empty, return *does not match*.

---

As an aside, you might want to clean up your Helmet code to something like this:

```js
app.use(helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
    directives: {
      // ...
    },
  },
}));
```

Your code uses `helmet()`, which includes some default CSP middleware, and then later overrides it with `helmet.contentSecurityPolicy()`. Not a huge deal, but slightly more correct to only use it once.

Comment: Thanks Evan, I will try it out. I just want to point out that I read your book `Express in Action`, and loved it. It was a fun to read, and I learned a lot.

Comment: It worked really well. Thank you. By the way, I have another small issue. Every time I update the `contentSecurityPolicy` for helmet, I need to make a change in the corresponding HTML file in order to apply the latest policies. I am using `nodemon` to re-spin my server each time a change is saved. But it seems like the latest policies cannot be applied with a change in the HTML file. Do you know what might be causing that issue?

Comment: My guess: Nodemon isn't restarting when you change your HTML. Not sure about the complexities of your app, though.